# et al. in connection to apacite

Tags: citing, apacite, multiple-citations

How can I change the citation of multiple authors of a document into the citation "(Author A, Author B, Author C, 2017)" in the first appearance of the citation and into "(Author A et al., 2017)" for any further citation of this source.

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the user guide of the `apacite` package? If so, did you come across the instructions `\shortcite` and `\fullcite` on page 13?

Comment: Incidentally, the citation call-out format -- list all authors the first time a given piece is cites, and list just the first author et al for subsequent citation call-outs -- is the default under `apacite`. You needn't do anything special.

Comment: It doesnt work though....

Comment: A remark such as "It doesn't work though" is completely unhelpful. *What* doesn't work? Did you maybe fail to load the `apacite` package?

Comment: How can I check if the apacite package loaded correctly.

Comment: Consult the log file. If a package didn't load correctly, it'll be noted in the log file.